# How to set up a formula to get equations of different parabolas but sharing the same focus?

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

this is my first question so I hope I got it right. Well I am trying to change the design of a parabolic solar concentrator and I was wondering if it was possible to have different equations of parabolas for the same focus (of the type $y=ax^2+bx+c$), since in my design I would like to keep the focus fixed. With the attached image, I think my point is better understood, you can see 3 parabolas, one more open than others, however all 3 have the same focus (I drew the red ones, so they have no equation). What I am looking for is that, to draw different parabolas modifying some parameter, but maintaining a focus that I initially set. That's all, I hope I have expressed my point well and if someone knows how I could get it, I would appreciate it, since I still have not achieved it.

[image: My goal]

Comment: Try to graph $y=ax^2$ for different values of $a$.

Comment: @Junior19: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Your figure seems to suggest that you want parabolas that have the same focus *and* the same vertex (bottom point), but simply get "wider". Unfortunately, there is only one parabola with a given focus-to-vertex distance. For what a family of same-focus parabolas really looks like, see, for instance, the figure in [MathWorld's "Confocal Parabolas" entry](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfocalParabolas.html). Please confirm that this is what you actually want. Cheers!

Comment: Why not just completing the square?
$ax^2+bx+c = (x-t)^2+z$ for some $t,z$. 
Then for all $h$, $h\cdot(x-t)^2+z$ should have some focus

Comment: Hi @Blue, I didn't know this was a topic in mathematics, and yes, I just wanted the focus to stay fixed (but from the image I attached, it looks like I also wanted the vertex fixed, sorry). On another note, many thanks to the others who responded, fortunately Laplacian gave me the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be a quite straightforward solution, and condsider it is not unique (I think).

The focus of a parabola of the type $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ has coordinates

$$F = \left(-\frac{b}{2a};\ \frac{1-\Delta}{4a}\right)$$

Where $\Delta = b^2-4ac$.

Now let's say you want a focus of coordinates (chosen by you) $F = (m, n)$ that is you need to have

$$
\begin{cases}
-\dfrac{b}{2a} = m 
\\\\
\dfrac{1 - \Delta}{4a} = n
\end{cases}
$$

With a bit of mathematics, they become

$$
\begin{cases}
b = -2am \\\\
4a^2m^2 - 4an - 4ac - 1 = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Now remember that you CHOSE the values for $m$ and $n$ so they are fixed numbers. The inverse problem is to find all the possible values for $a, b, c$ that satisfy the equations above to give you those values of $m$ and $n$, that is: the same focus for every parabola.

This can be done now by solving the second equations for $a$, getting

$$a = \frac{(n+c)\pm\sqrt{(n+c)^2 + m^2}}{2m^2}$$

and getting back to $b$ you obtain

$$b = -\frac{(n+c)\pm\sqrt{(n+c)^2 + m^2}}{m}$$

Now as I said, $m, n$ are numbers you chose from the beginning. You just need to pick some value for $c$ that satisfies you, and you're done.

So eventually, choosing two fixed numbers $m, n$ and varying the value of $c$, the focus of a parabola is $F = (m, n)$ and all the parabolas of the form

$$y = \frac{(n+c)\pm\sqrt{(n+c)^2 + m^2}}{2m^2} x^2 -\frac{(n+c)\pm\sqrt{(n+c)^2 + m^2}}{m} x + c$$

will have the same foci of coordinates $F = (m, n)$.

Comment: First of all, hi @Laplacian and thanks a lot for your time and your answer,

but is strange the behavior of your solution when the signs are not + and +, as can be seen in the gif I attach. I would expect that the focus is always inside the parabola, but this only happens when the solution is with + and +, in the other cases the focus is outside the parabola at some point. This part is important because the incident sun rays should concentrate on the focus and it does not make sense that the focus is outside; anyway the solution with + and + is enough for me.

https://gifyu.com/image/STiSl

Answer (score 2):

The focus-directrix property of parabolas tells us that, for any point $P$ on the curve,
$$\text{distance from $P$ to the focus} \;=\; \text{distance from $P$ to the directrix} \tag1$$

Let the parabola have a fixed focus $F=(m,n)$. If the parabola's axis of symmetry is presumed vertical, then its directrix is a horizontal line; say $y=d$. Writing $P=(x,y)$, the distances to $F$ and the directrix are easy to compute, so that $(1)$ becomes
$$\sqrt{(x-m)^2+(y-n)^2} \;=\; |y-d| \tag2$$

Squaring, gathering terms, and isolating $y$ gives

> $$y = \frac{1}{2(n-d)}\left(\,(x-m)^2+n^2-d^2\,\right) \tag{$\star$}$$

(This becomes [@Lapacian's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4512667/409) (replacing "$\pm$" with "$+$") by taking $d=-c+\sqrt{(n+c)^2+m^2}$.)

Comment: True @Blue, thanks for this other point of view, I guess this is what Laplacian meant when he said: "and condsider it is not unique (I think)". Greetings.